# Separating txt file to many csv files with PHP

Tags: php, csv, text-files

So I was able to parse the txt file into a csv file

```
$data = array();
while ($line= fgets ($fh)) {
$stack = array($LAUS,$FIPS,$CountyName,$Date,$_CLF,$_EMP,$_UNEMP,$RATE);
        array_push($data, $stack);
}
$file = fopen('file.csv','w');

foreach ($data as $fields) {
fputcsv($file, $fields,',','"');
 }

fclose($file);
```

My question is, what is the best way to create multiple csv files that are seperated by Month (also the year, like Jan01.csv, Jan02.csv).

Comment: I don't want to sound condescending, but I guess the "best way" is, well, doing it. What are you stuck with? Where is the month data coming from? I don't see any in your code

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was a little vague. Is there a way to create a variable name that contains a variable? like $data_$Jan01, $data_Jan02. That way I can check which $month and $year it is to send that stack to the right data array. From there I know how to output to different csv's

Comment: Also, there is no defined range of csv files so I don't want to hard code them if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a guess at the formatting of your date

```
while ($line = fgets ($fh)) {
    // Not sure where you're getting these values, but I'm assuming it's correct
    $stack = array($LAUS,$FIPS,$CountyName,$Date,$_CLF,$_EMP,$_UNEMP,$RATE);

    // Assuming $Date looks like this '2011-10-04 15:00:00'
    $filename = date('My', strtotime($Date)) . '.csv';
    $file = fopen($filename,'a+');
    fputcsv($file, $stack,',','"');
    fclose($file);
}
```

This will be a little slow since you're opening and closing files constantly, but since I don't know the size of your original data set I don't want to use up all the memory caching the result before I write it.

Be aware that running this multiple times will end up with duplicate data being inserted into your CSV files. You may want to add some code to remove/clear out any currently existing CSV files before you run this bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this is close but the $stack is one line of code which from my original code is pushed to the data array, then the data is pushed to csv file. How would I go about throwing the stack to the appropriate $data array without hard coding $dataJan01, $dataJan02. I realize I can run the code and just pull the $stacks that are appropriate for that month/year but I was hoping there was a way I can avoid that loop

Comment: Maybe you could give me an example of the data stored in `$stack` I'd have a better idea of what I have to work with.

Comment: Wait, you had it right. I'm new to php and didnt see that 'a+'. I didn't realize that meant to append. Thanks for your help. I don't think it's exactly what I had in mind but this seems the way to do it.